# Enable paging or scrollbars for polymer paper-listbox

Tags: polymer-1.0, custom-component

Code below will display list of users from the database and i would like to enable paging / scrollbars for paper-listbox. Any help would be appreciated

```
<paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{getSelectedItemID}}" on-iron-select="_itemSelected">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[getActiveCompanies]]" flex filter="{{Filter(filterValue)}}">
            <iron-item value="[[item.ID]]" class="primary">{{item.CompanyCode}} - {{item.CompanyName}}</iron-item>
        </template>
    </paper-listbox>
```

Comment: don't say thanks and don't sign posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to import this : iron-scroll-target-behavior.html

after you can try this :

```
<div id="scrollable-element" style="display:block;height:300px;overflow-y: auto;">
<x-element scroll-target="scrollable-element">

<paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{getSelectedItemID}}" on-iron-select="_itemSelected">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[getActiveCompanies]]" flex filter="{{Filter(filterValue)}}">
        <iron-item value="[[item.ID]]" class="primary">{{item.CompanyCode}} - {{item.CompanyName}}</iron-item>
    </template>
  </paper-listbox>

</x-element>
</div>
```

good luck !

Comment: Thanks, it helped in my case